# Render a modal with a specific user's data

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can you guys give me an idea how to pass data to a modal according to a specific user? I have an array containing user data. When I click on the corresponding user, I need to open a modal with his data like name and email. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you would solve this through React's props, as follows:

```
export interface UserData {
  name: string
  email: string
}

export interface ModalProps {
  user: UserData
}

export const Modal: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({ user }) => {
  // TODO: render modal here
  return <></>
}
```

It would be rendered as follows:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return <Modal user={{ name: 'John', email: 'john@doe.io' }} />
}
```

If your user changes, you have to define a state in the respective component and call its setter function to render the component again:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState<UserData>({
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john@doe.io'
  })

  // if needed, call setUser(newUser) to update the modal

  return <Modal user={user} />
}
```

You'd better get to know the React basics. The React docs are a good foundation:

- [Hello World](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html)
- [Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)
- [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
- [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)
- and so on...